How to raise linter error `The operand can't be null, so the condition is always 'true'.`
In an app update, we changed a nullable boolean from nullable to default to false.
  @override
  bool hasChanged() {
    final diff = changeTracker.diff(appFormCheck);
    return diff != null;
  }

Now the code has hundreds of the old line above with various forms causing all sorts of bugs.

The operand can't be null, so the condition is always 'true'.

The linter knows about them but How to make those an error ?
I tried
linter:
  rules:
    - avoid_null_checks_in_equality_operators

But it does not raise errors

By default, when you run dart analyze on the code, you should be getting a warning: warning • FILE:LINE • The operand can't be null, so the condition is always 'true'. Remove the condition. • unnecessary_null_comparison.  Therefore you need to change the severity of unnecessary_null_comparison to be an error.

that worked! Thank you for the tip. How do you know if it is a linter rule or an analyzer rule  or compiler errors. I still don't understand very well why there are 3 types of error . Is it possible change the severity of linter rules ?

Compiler errors are from the compiler. analysis_options.yaml controls the analyzer.  The analyzer has diagnostic messages and linter rules.  I'm not exactly sure what the criteria are for what's a diagnostic message and what's a linter rule, but I think diagnostic messages usually are more objectively wrong whereas linter rules usually are for things that are more subjective or for things that might be wrong.  There definitely seems to be a gray area where there's some overlap.
